# C++: assignment operator of class with dynamic array of pointers to abstract base class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, abstract-class

So I have an abstract base with 2 derived classes, and a container with `A** arr;`; now, i want to overload assignment operator, but doing `arr[i] = new A(other.arr[i]);` obviously doesnt work. How do I work around this? Do i need to use `dynamic_cast` or something, or are there more "elegant" solutions?

```
class A {
private:
    int someMember;
public:
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
    A();
    ~A();
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    int someOtherMember;
public:
    virtual void someMethod(){}
    B();
    ~B();
};

class C : public A
{
private:
    int anotherMember;
public:
    virtual void someMethod(){
    C();
    ~C();
};

class Container
{
private:
    A** arr;
    int arrSize;
public:
    Container();
    ~Container();

    //How do I implement this?
    Container& operator=(Container& other);
};

Container & Container::operator=(Container & other)
{
    //Clear current array
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        delete arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;

    //create new array
    this->arr = new A*[other.arrSize];

    //fill new array
    for (int i = 0; i < other.arrSize; i++)
    {
        //doesnt work, since A is abstract base class
        arr[i] = new A(other.arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Using vectors is not allowed as this is an assignment for school (teacher explicitly said no `std::vector`)

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574075/virtual-constructor-idiom-and-factory-design)?

Comment: @LogicStuff while that would work, my teacher _also_ explicitly told us to overload assignment operator. I guess `operator=` could implement something like what you linked but I'm not sure that's what he's looking for

Comment: By the way, your `operator=` implementation is not exception safe. If any of the calls to `new` throw (possible but unlikely) or your copy constructors throw (more likely), then your `Container` will be left in an invalid state and will probably crash your program (not to mention memory leaks). Getting memory management code correct can be difficult. You should use `unique_ptr`if possible rather than using `new`and`delete`manually. Then use the copy-and-swap idiom to implement `operator=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `clone` virtual function to `A` that returns a copy of the concrete object as an `A*`. Call this within `Container:: operator=` to copy the objects polymorphically.

Answer (score 1):

Well, RTTI is not something I would use in production code, but in this case it should be fine. You could do:

```
A* ref = other.arr[i];
if(typeid(ref) == typeid(B*))
    arr[i] = new B(*dynamic_cast<B*>(ref));
else if(typeid(ref) == typeid(C*))
    arr[i] = new C(*dynamic_cast<C*>(ref));
else
    //handle error or change else if to else
```

Of course that requires that `B` and `C` have defined copy constructors and implemented pure-virtual function from `A`. Also you should make A destructor virtual.

Comment: This is what I had in mind, and I've been told RTTI is not good practice (which is why I was looking for other solutions) but I haven't been told why. An explanation as to why this is the case would be great if you don't mind!

Comment: RTTI is not easily expandable. For example, if you had another class `D` inherit from `A`, you would have to modify your `Container::operator=` (add another `else if`). That sucks, right? Why would you have to modify some container because you created another class? For this, polymorphism is much better, and you don't have to modify everything everywhere. See LogicStuff comment.

Comment: @EliasFinoli Apart from being inefficient compared to a single virtual function call, this approach also hard-codes the set of sub-classes that can be used with `Container`, making it inflexible and harder to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, makes sense.